How extensive was the ceremonial law pre-Sinai?
The Israelites did not receive the law until they came to Mt. Sinai in Exodus 19. Yet some pre-Sinai passages seem to indicate that they were already keeping a rudimentary version of the law at this point.
In Exodus 19:14-15, Moses tells the people to consecrate themselves, including abstinence from sexual intercourse. Was this common ritual practice before the laws about ceremonial uncleanness were given?
Exodus 19:22 mentions priests, so presumably there was already a well established ritual structure.
Obviously some rules already existed before Sinai (circumcision, the sabbath, sacrifices) but maybe this system was much more extensive than that.
To what extent was the ceremonial law “new” to the Israelites at Sinai?
Are there other examples of the Israelites following ceremonial laws before Sinai?

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Consider cross posting this question on judaism.stackexchange.com as well

@Bryce W don't forget clean and unclean meat laws existed before the Law was given at Mt. Sinai too. The Sabbath was created at the end of creation week and it pre-existed before the Law was given.

This answer will be confined to purely "ceremonial" aspects of the law, ie, practices of religious rites outside of the moral law of the 10 commandments.  However, the appendix below shows that even the 10 commandments were well-understood well before Sinai.
General
There is a tantalizing verse that says that Abraham kept all the "law" -

Gen 26:5 - Abraham listened to My voice and kept My charge, My
commandments, My statutes, and My laws.”

Exactly which laws & statutes is not defined.
Sacrifices
Sacrifices were offered from the earliest of times that included the following:

Gen 4:1-7 - Cain and Able offered sacrifices
Gen 7:2, 8 - Noah made provision for sacrifices before the flood
Gen 8:20, 21 - Noah offered as soon as he exited the Ark after the flood
Gen 12:7, 8, 13:4, 18 - Abraham offered sacrifices on various altars
Gen 26:25 - Isaac built sacrificial altars
Gen 31:1, 54, 33:20, 35:3, 7, 46:1 - Jacob offered sacrifices on altars

Circumcision
Circumcision was introduced as part of the Abrahamic Covenant in Gen 17:10-14, 23-26.  Abraham also circumcised Isaac in Gen 21:4.
Blood Prohibition
The prohibition against eating blood, or any meat containing blood, was introduced as part of the Noahide Covenant in Gen 9:4-6.
The written ceremonial law introduced as Sinai simply systematized what had largely been the common practice previously by adding many regulations and an annual calendar of ceremonial rites.
APPENDIX 1 - Moral Law of Ten Commandments before Sinai
The following (far from exhaustive) list shows that people knew of the law and ten commandments well before the formal giving at Mt Sinai.
Commandment #1 – Worship only YHWH:

Gen 22:5, 24:26, 48, 52 all describe worship of the true God of heaven, YHWH.
Gen 35:1-4 – Jacob instructs his whole household to eliminate all foreign gods

Commandment #2 – Idolatry prohibited

Gen 31:32-35 – Jacob clearly understood that idolatry was forbidden.
Gen 35:1-4 – Jacob instructs his whole household to eliminate all foreign gods

Commandment #3 –Cursing and taking the name of the LORD in vain prohibited

Job 1:5 – When these celebrations ended—sometimes after several days—Job would purify his children. He would get up early in the morning and offer a burnt offering for each of them. For Job said to himself, “Perhaps my children have sinned and have cursed God in their hearts.” This was Job’s regular practice.

Commandment #4 – Sabbath worship

Gen 2:1-3 – Thus the heavens and the earth were completed in all their vast array.  And by the seventh day God had finished the work He had been doing; so on that day He rested from all His work.  Then God blessed the seventh day and sanctified it, because on that day He rested from all the work of creation that He had accomplished.
Gen 16 also records the incident with manna and that collecting manna on the seventh-day Sabbath was forbidden

Commandment #5 – Respect for parents, elders and authority

Gen 28:6, 7 tells of the story of Jacob following his mother’s advice.  Respect for parents is built into the very fabric of the patriarchal stories in Genesis.

Commandment #6 – Sanctity of Human life

Gen 4:8-12, 15 records Cain’s punishment for the sin of murder
Gen 9:5, 6 records that murder was prohibited under the ancient Noahide covenant

Commandment #7 – Adultery prohibited

Gen 12:10-20, 20:1-17, 26:6-11 all record “adultery narratives” in which the patriarch is (correctly) chided for almost tricking a pagan king into committing adultery
Gen 19 records the appalling events involving attempted pack-rape of the two angels
Gen 39:7-9 – Joseph calls Potiphar’s wife proposal “a great evil and sin against God”.
Gen 49:4 – Reuben is scalded for his sin of incest
Gen 34 – the story of Dinah records a heinous incident involving her defilement (plus murder and lying)

Commandment #8 – Stealing prohibited and respect for property

Gen 30:33 – Laban and Jacob discuss the problem of stealing of wages and property
Gen 31:32-35 – Laban is angry about the sin of stealing the household gods

Commandment #9 – Lying prohibited; insistence of honesty and integrity

Gen 4 – the story of Cain being punished, among other things for not being honest with Abel and God in his statements
Gen 12:10-20, 20:1-17, 26:6-11 all record “adultery narratives” in which the patriarch is (correctly) chided for lying to a pagan king about their marital status
In the story of Jacob, he is pejoratively called Jacob = “deceiver”, Gen 27:36.

Commandment #10 – Coveting prohibited

Gen 3:6 – the woman is tricked by the serpent using the sin of covetousness


At the time of the exodus, ALL of the things you listed Circumcision, Sabbath and offerings WERE NOT being practiced in Egypt. Circumcision wasn't reintroduced to Israel until they entered the Land.  The first generation that left Egypt died in the wilderness.  Circumcision is a sign of faithfulness and thus those who left Egypt were not faith and were NOT permitted to enter the promised land because of their rebelliousness and their refusal to believe and obey God.

You say "reintroduced", which implies that it was practiced pre-Sinai, just not continuously.

circumcision - see Genesis 17:10 This is my covenant, which you shall keep, between me and you and your offspring after you: Every male among you shall be circumcised.

The encounter in Exodus 4:24-26 where Zipporah circumcises Moses’s sons would seem to indicate (by omission) that Moses was already circumcised. Moses’s circumcision might also be the reason Pharaoh’s daughter immediately identified him as a Hebrew child.
Circumcision, Sabbaths, and sacrifices all have their roots in events before the Exodus. Do you have a reason for saying they were not practiced pre-Sinai?
Do you have
